# Blender Cheat Sheet

Tags: workflow

I'm retired and cannot afford C4D anymore, so I'm switching to Blender 2.8.  Is there a simple, one or two page file that list at least the most used shortcut keys?

Comment: 2 pages for a often used shortcut *in Blender*? That's quite difficult, but there is bunch of pdf file over each forum with google search. Also, Blender can switch those keymap to **Industry Standard** to mimic those shortcut in other software (MAYA,3ds,C4D). You might try it if you don't want to learn new key.

Answer (score 1):

There are two 2.8 cheat sheets that I'm aware of:

- [Blender Guru (Andrew Price)](https://mailchi.mp/ef5b15a32043/subscribe-to-the-newsletter)
- [Zacharias Reinhardt](https://cgboost.com/resources/)

However the former is 7 pages and the latter 12 pages long, so not quite as compact as you were expecting. Both require a registration to their newsletter in order to download the PDF (copies may be found elsewhere on the web).